# Extra back slash appended to string when reading attribute value containing a back slash

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have a web page that has the following HTML element.

```
<input id="Email" type="text" arguments="" val_validationerrormessage="" 
val_regexexpression="/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/" 
val_isrequired="True" val_maxlength="0" val_minlength="0" 
command="" val_isnumeric="False" selectedvalues="">
```

When using jQuery to obtain the value of control\argument val_regexexpression, an extra "\" is appended to the string and it's contents is like this "/^\\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/" as you can see this is different from the original string.

I obtain this value is in the following way

```
var Val_RegexExpression = Control.attr("Val_RegexExpression");
```

How can I retrieve the original string?

Comment: That's just character escaping. What are you trying to achieve? And how do you check the value? Did you `console.log` it?

Comment: This is not the case here: http://jsfiddle.net/YMk63/

Comment: it's dependent on viewing app. For me on (vomit) windows 7 x64 with chrome 32.0.1700.107 checking out @A.Wolff 's link shows `/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/`. As @freakish says, its character escaping, but what you see is only how the app your using veiws/presents it. Yes escaping will occur regardless so no fret.